# Measurability with respect to tail sigma algebra of limsup

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm trying to proof this:

**Theorem**

Let be $(X_n)_{n \ge 1}$ a sequence of real random variables. Let 
$$S_n:= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k $$
Then $$\underset{n \to \infty}{\text{limsup }}S_n(\omega)$$
is $\mathcal{T}$-measurable, where 
$$\mathcal{T} := \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \sigma(X_n, X_{n+1}, \dots)$$

I will use this

**Lemma**

If $X_1, \dots X_n$ are real random variables defined on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable, then $f(X_1, \dots X_n)$ is $\sigma(X_1, \dots, X_n) - \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ measurable, where $\sigma(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ is the smallest sigma-algebra with respect to each $X_i$ is measurable.

**Proof**

It suffices to proof that $\underset{n \to \infty}{\text{limsup }}S_n$ is $\sigma(X_p, X_{p+1}, \dots)$ measurable for each $p \ge 1$.

Let $p \ge 1$ be arbitrary and fixed, and let $H \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$;

First I observe that $\underset{n \to \infty}{\text{limsup }}S_n = \underset{n \to \infty, n \ge p}{\text{limsup }}S_n$

I have to proof that $(\underset{n \to \infty}{\text{limsup }}S_n)^{-1}(H)  =(\underset{n \to \infty, n \ge p}{\text{limsup }}S_n)^{-1}(H) \in \sigma(X_p, X_{p+1}, \dots)$:

$(\underset{n \to \infty}{\text{limsup }}S_n)^{-1}(H) = (\underset{n \to \infty, n \ge p}{\text{limsup }}S_n)^{-1}(H) = \{\omega \in \Omega : \underset{n \to \infty, n \ge p}{\text{limsup }}S_n(\omega) \in H \} =\{\omega \in \Omega : \underset{n \to \infty, n \ge p}{\text{limsup }}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k(\omega) \in H \} = \{\omega \in \Omega : \underset{n \to \infty, n \ge p}{\text{limsup }}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} X_k(\omega) + \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=p}^{n} X_k(\omega) \in H \}= \{\omega \in \Omega : \underset{n \to \infty, n \ge p}{\text{limsup }}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=p}^{n} X_k(\omega) \in H \}=\{\omega \in \Omega : \underset{n \to \infty, n \ge p}{\text{limsup }}Y_{m,p}(\omega) \in H \}=\{\omega \in \Omega : \bigcap_{n=p}^{\infty} \bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty} Y_{m,p}(\omega) \in H \} = \bigcap_{n=p}^{\infty} \bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty}\{\omega \in \Omega : Y_{m,p}(\omega) \in H \}$

Now, $Y_{m,p}(\omega) = g(X_p(\omega), \dots, X_m(\omega))$ where $g: \mathbb{R}^{m-p+1} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous map and then measurable. By the lemma we have that $Y_{m,p}$ is $\sigma(X_p, \dots, X_m)$ measurable and then $Y_{m,p}$ is $\sigma(X_p, \dots)$ measurable.
Then $\{\omega \in \Omega : Y_{m,p}(\omega) \in H \} \in \sigma(X_p, \dots)$ and, since it is a sigma algebra, also $\bigcap_{n=p}^{\infty} \bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty}\{\omega \in \Omega : Y_{m,p}(\omega) \in H \} \in \sigma(X_p, \dots)$, and then $(\underset{n \to \infty}{\text{limsup }}S_n)^{-1}(H) \in \sigma(X_p, \dots)$ wich completes the proof.

Is it correct?

Comment: What the heck is $Y_{m,p}$...? The idea of your proof is correct, but your proof is kind of overcomplicated. It suffices to note that $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=p}^n X_i$$ and that the right-hand side is clearly $\sigma(X_i; i \geq p)$-measurable for all $p$.

Comment: I'm sorry if it is not clear; $Y_{m,p} := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=p}^{m} X_k$. I didn't know if $\limsup_{n \to \infty}W_n$ of r.v. $W_n$ $\mathcal{F}$ measurable was also $\mathcal{F}$ measurable so i checked it by the definition of measurability. It is complicated...but is it wrong?

Comment: Yeah, the last part of it where you want to show that the limsup is measurable. Note that $\bigcap_n \bigcup_m Y_{m,p}$ doesn't make any sense (intersection and union of a real number?!?)

Comment: You're right! So what should i write? 
$$\{\omega \in \Omega : \underset{n \to \infty, n \ge p}{\text{limsup }}Y_{n,p}(\omega) \in H \} = \{\omega \in \Omega : \lim_{n \to \infty, n \ge p} \sup_{m \ge n} Y_{m,p}(\omega) \in H \} = \bigcap_{n=p}^{\infty} \bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty} \{\omega \in \Omega : Y_{m,p}(\omega) \in H \} $$